# Rate of Change in Neural Plasticity

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, plasticity

I read that children brain has more neural plasticity compared to adults, with the possible explanation as appeared in [this](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/262/why-does-neuroplasticity-decrease-in-adults) question, pertaining to synaptic changes, where if you learn something, the synapse change occurs in structure to reflect the new learned stuff. I am curious to know if there is a method/research that perhaps quantifies this, in other words an adult can potentially acquire/learn new things daily, does that mean that the rate of change quantifying neural plasticity is few hours or perhaps one day in adults?

Comment: The term *neural plasticity* can reflect a great many things, from subcellular stuff happening at the synaptic level, to gross restructuring of the cerebral cortex involving large swaths of tissue. Can you add backgrounds to what process you are referring to exactly, and add relevant links and sources?

Comment: That doesn't really help I'm afraid. Where are you looking at? Synaptic changes, receptor changes, DNA expression, cell proliferation, structural changes....

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly; these comments likely won't be here forever.

Comment: @AliceD i have edited the question.